# Filtering with SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, search, filtering

I'm trying to write a SQL query for filtering people in a data set.

There are some "facets", which are things like "How old is the person?", "How tall is the person?".

There are some "buckets" for each facet. For example, the "How old?" facet might have buckets "0-20", "21-40", "40+".

There are some "memberships", which is a join table to state that a person belongs in a particular bucket.

My model looks like this:

```
  Facet
    |
   /|\
  Bucket
    |
   /|\
Membership
   \|/
    |
  Person
```

The part I'm struggling with is, to be able to do the filter, I need to do an intersection across facets.

For example, I want to be able choose "0-20" and "21-40" for "How old?" and "0-140" for "How tall?". The people returned should be:

(People in bucket "0-20" OR People in bucket "21-40") AND People in bucket "0-140"

I'm not really sure how to do this. I can do the "OR" easily enough with an "IN" clause, e.g. IN (1, 2, 3), but I'm not sure about the "AND". I saw that SQL has an "INTERSECT" keyword, but I'm not sure if this is the right approach.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

**Edit**: Here's the (simplified) schema:

facets: id

buckets: id, facet_id

memberships: person_id, bucket_id

people: id

All fields are integers.

**Edit:** Here's my best query so far.

```
select group_concat(p.id) as "people for facet",
b.facet_id from people p
join memberships m on m.person_id = p.id
join buckets b on m.bucket_id = b.id
where b.id in (1, 3)
group by b.facet_id;
```

I now need to intersect the "people for facet" results together.

Comment: School work? Table definitions, some sample data, wanted result, etc. What have you come up with so far?

Comment: Can the "buckets" be shared among "facets"?  Or is a given bucket only in one facet?

Comment: A given bucket is in a single facet. i.e. it has a foreign key to the facet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that any given bucket is only part of a single facet, then there is a pretty elegant solution.  The challenge is looking at the problem the right way.  So, if you want users that match all your facets,

```
select b.userid
from buckets b
where b.bucketid in ( . . . )
group by b.userid
having count(distinct b.facetid) = # of facets;
```

The idea is that you have a list of buckets and represent the facets that you want.  You want to be sure that each "facet" has at least one matching bucket, which is what the `having` clause does.

Comment: That assumption is correct. I'll give this a go - thanks! Will this also work if buckets in a facet are not mutually exclusive, e.g. "Facial hair?" might include "Beard" and "Moustache", of which some people may have both.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think this is quite right. The query doesn't reference the join table "memberships". I don't really understand what you mean by "number of facets". It should be all facets for which you have chosen buckets.

Comment: @Chris you'll have to add the proper joins, there's no info about table structures in the question, so this answer just shows the basic method.

Comment: @Chris . . . This will work if they are not mutually exclusive -- assuming you only need to match one bucket per facet.  And, yes, the "# facets" is the number of facets represented by the buckets in the bucket list.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Gordon. I got it at last! Your topsy-turvy way of thinking about the problem helped.

Here's my solution:

```
select p.* from memberships m
join people p on m.person_id = p.id
join buckets b on m.bucket_id = b.id
where b.id in (1, 3)
group by m.person_id
having count(distinct b.facet_id) = (
  select count(distinct b.facet_id) from buckets b
  where b.id in (1, 3)
);
```

The input is the list of buckets (1, 3).

I used a subquery to count the number of facets for those buckets. Perhaps there's a more performant way, but I think that'll be executed quickly anyway.

I'm going to test this across a large data set and see how it performs.

Thanks again.